# How to load forms using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple login and register form using ajax
This is my code:

```
function loadRegistrationForm() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "registrationform.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

.

```
<div id="container">
  --->LOGIN FORM
  <a onclick="loadRegistrationForm">Register?</a>
</div>
```

but whenever I click the link the registration form will only flash for a second then it gets back to the login form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the code for the form?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `onclick="loadRegistrationForm()"`? (I.e., add parentheses to actually call the function, otherwise nothing will happen.) Also, you should specify an `href` so that the link behaves like a normal link in terms of receiving focus, etc.

Comment: yea. show us the form. the culprit might be there residing.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
onclick="loadRegistrationForm()"
```

instead of

```
onclick="loadRegistrationForm"
```

Comment: The `()` are important, but the lack thereof doesn't explain the behaviour the OP described.

Comment: The question said "whenever I click the link the registration form will only flash for a second then it gets back to the login form" - how do the missing parentheses explain that? Why would adding them fix that?